# Converting ISO 8601 date format with timezone in python

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601

I am attempting to convert the following date (2012-12-25T08:52:00-05:00) to a datetime object in python. However, I cannot figure out what the **-05:00** part of the date is referencing. I am simply trying to perform the following:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2012-12-25T08:52:00-05:00','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

But this comes up with an expected '**ValueError: unconverted data remains**'. I'm just trying to figure out what the last part of the date is used for so that I can convert that string to a proper datetime object in python.

Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your date seems to be in the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, I don't think `datetime` handles the timezone information at the end of the string format.

You can use `pip install python-dateutil`, its parser can return a `datetime` object :

```
import dateutil.parser
datestr = '2012-12-25T08:52:00-05:00'
dateutil.parser.parse(datestr)
>>> datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 25, 8, 52, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
```

Comment: On UTC-systems `parse('1998-01-01T00:00:00Z')` gives `datetime.datetime(1998, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzlocal())` on non-UTC systems it returns `datetime.datetime(1998, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())` - a very odd inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

The `-05:00` indicates the timezone offset from UTC, i.e. `%z` would be the correct strptime argument to parse it.

If the time is UTC the offset might be indicated using `Z`, e.g. `2012-12-25T08:52:00Z`. Not sure if `%z` would actually accept this...